# Change the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
 SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
 String formatDate = p.format(temp.EXPIRATION_DATE()); 

//EXPIRATION_DATE is a DATE data type.
```

I am able to get the output as expected but when i am trying to set it back i,
need the desired output to be in DATE type not the String.
But if the parse it ot try casting it with DATE,like this

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
convertedDate = (Date) formatter.format(date);
```

My output is coming like this:

```
Fri Aug 23 16:07:11 EDT 2013.
```

I need the output to be in `2013/08/23` format and it should be in DATE data type.
Is there any way i can achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: Formatting is display purpose, parse is to represent date. I think you are confused in understanding usage.

Comment: The output you don't like is what you see when you try to print a Date object directly (you're looking at the output of `Date.toString()`).  If you want to display a specific format for a given date, use `SimpleDateFormat.format()` after specifying the format you want.

Comment: You should view a Date object as nothing more than a wrapper around a number that represents an instant in time.  The value of the number is the number of miliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.  To convert a Date into a human readable string with a specified format, you use a SimpleDateFormat to _create_ a String _from_ a Date.

Comment: what you guys have said is true,but when i parse i will get the ouput as Fri Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 2014

Comment: When you print a `Date` object directly, it will be formatted using a fixed format that looks like "Fri Aug 15 ...". You still don't understand that a `Date` object **does not have a format**. Parsing means: converting a `String` into a `Date`. Note that the resulting `Date` does not remember what format the `String` was in.

Comment: @Jesper: I am sorry i know i am troubling you guys for a very simple case,but my problem is i need to set a DATE object i.e public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
  this.expirationDate = expirationDate;} and it should be like 2013/08/22.Hope i made it clear

Comment: What is clear is that you don't understand how Dates and Strings are related (or **not** related).  A Date is a Date and it has **absolutely nothing to do with** any kind of formatting information.  To print a Date in a given format, you need to convert it to a String using a SimpleDateFormat object.  When you do that you will have two completely separate objects: one will be a Date, the other will be a String.  The two objects know nothing about one another.  You can represent any Date object in any format by using a SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Just to repeat one more time: a Date is nothing more than a number that represents an instant in time.  You can use a SimpleDateFormat to create a String from a Date.  The String you create can have any format you want, but it will have **no effect** on the Date object you use to create the String.  The exact same Date object can be used to create multiple Strings in different formats.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String formatDate = p.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(formatDate);
    }


}
```

`format` returns the formatted date.  It doesn't modify the `Date` object.  If you want to print out the date in the format, you have to print out the response of `format`.

Comment: How can i update my date object in to 2013/08/12,it tried using new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); i am able to change it but when i try to upadate my object it is avaible in String.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Answer (score 1):

> I need the output to be in `2013/08/23` format and it should be in DATE data type. Is there any way i can achieve this.

No, that is not possible.

A `Date` object only contains a date value. It does not have any information about the format in which to display the date. To display a date in a certain format, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` - you specify the format on the `SimpleDateFormat` object, and then use it to convert the `Date` to a `String`.